# Strange issue about # in url

Tags: url, get

```
http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php#?formid=1
```

And

```
http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php?formid=1
```

I failed to retrieve `$_GET['formid']` in the first one,why?

The content of `test/editformquestions.php` is simply:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['formid'];
?>
```

Comment: please rephrase your question since the correct answer given below isn't addressing what you aren't clearly asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Characters after the hash # are to be used by the browser, they are not sent back to the server.

Answer (score 3):

`#` is a hash character, not a GET variable.

You need to put the `?` before any hashes, otherwise the $_GET array will not be populated.

Comment: Ok, tell me what i didn't get.

Comment: The 1st url containing "#" also sends request to test/editformquestions.php,but can't retrieve the $_GET parameters in that file.

Comment: Exactly. it goes to editformquestions.php, of course. But it DOESN'T PASS IN THE GET VARIABLE BECAUSE OF THE `#` CHAR IN FRONT OF IT.
( SEE OTHER MORE IN-DEPTH ANSWERS ABOVE ).

Comment: In fact I'm asking:why $_GET array is not populated ?

Comment: If you wrote `?form=1#` that would work.
Because the querystring parser ignores it because it sees something other than the `?` char, so it stops execution.

Answer (score 2):

`#` is used by the browser, and is never sent to the server. Everything after a `#` (regardless of what it is) is used by the browser to jump to a location on the page.

So:

```
http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php#?formid=1
```

Will be split as follows:

- Server request to `http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php`
- Browser then searches in page for:

  ```
  <a name="?formid=1">named anchor tag</a>
  ```

What you should do is:

```
http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php?formid=1&othervar=2#anchorinpage
```

Or, if you need the `#` in a query-string parameter:

```
http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php?formid=1&othervar=textwith%23init
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#` is fragment identifier for a URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

To use it as part of an array variable you'll need to url encode it:

`'#' becomes '%23' when url-encoded`

In javascript you can accomplish url encoding with the [`encodeURI()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp) function

Comment: It's ahead of "?",not behind!

Answer (score 0):

A HTTP URL may contain these parts:

- protocol: `http://`
- domain: `localhost`
- path: `/test/editformquestions.php`
- query string: `?formid=1` - always starts with a `?`
- fragment: `#something` - always starts with a `#` - whatever comes after the `#` mark is NOT sent to the server.

What you have in your first example (`http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php#?formid=1`) is a fragment containing this: `#?formid=1`. It does not matter that there's a `?` in the fragment; as soon as it's behind the `#`, it is not sent from the browser.

So, in essence, you are sending to the server only this: `http://localhost/test/editformquestions.php` - as you can see, there *is* no formid in that request.